# Inserting a line break within a string where text wraps?

Tags: c#, newline, repeater, line-breaks, breadcrumbs

I want to insert a line break into a string whenever it wraps at the "wrong" spot (the string in question being a breadcrumb style navigation within a repeater called "BreadCrumbsRepeater"). Right now, the text will wrap regardless of whether it's breaking up a product name or not. For example:

Home  >  Additional Products  >  Stain & Finish  >  ZAR Stain & Finish  >  ZAR Ultra Max Wood Stain >  ZAR Ultra Max **[LINE BREAK]** Espresso Wood Stain - Quart

What I would like to do in the above example, for instance, is insert a line break before the ">" symbol right before "ZAR Ultra Max ....". I have read about Environment.NewLine, but I am not sure how to apply it a such specific occurrences. Is it even possible to do this?

As an important side note, the repeater is located within a div with a set width (without the set width, the text will run off the border of the page). Also, I have managed to obtain the total number of characters inside the repeater at any given time.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Here is the template code which has the repeater:

```
    <div class="breadCrumbs categoryBreadCrumbs">
    <div class="innerSection">
        <div class="content" style="top: 10px;float: left; clear:both; margin:0 auto; width:650px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; left: 244px; position: relative; white-space: inherit; overflow: inherit; font-size: 11px;">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HomeLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl="" Text="Home "></asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:Repeater ID="BreadCrumbsRepeater" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <span id="crumbs"><asp:HyperLink ID="BreadCrumbsLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("NavigateUrl")%>' Text=' <%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:HyperLink></span>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:Label ID="CurrPageBCLbl" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold;" /> 
            <br /><asp:Label ID="foo" runat="server" visible="false"/>
            <br /><asp:Label ID="numChar" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
 [Description("Displays bread crumbs for the current category")]
    public partial class CategoryBreadCrumbs : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        int _CategoryId = 0;
        bool _HideLastNode = false;

        public int CategoryId
        {
            get { return _CategoryId; }
            set { _CategoryId = value; }
        }

        [Browsable(true), DefaultValue(true)]
        [Description("If true last node is hidden")]
        public bool HideLastNode
        {
            get { return _HideLastNode; }
            set { _HideLastNode = value; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CategoryId = AbleCommerce.Code.PageHelper.GetCategoryId();

            Webpage _webpage = WebpageDataSource.Load(PageHelper.GetWebpageId());
            Product _product = ProductDataSource.Load(PageHelper.GetProductId());
            Category _category = CategoryDataSource.Load(PageHelper.GetCategoryId());

            HomeLink.NavigateUrl = AbleCommerce.Code.NavigationHelper.GetHomeUrl();
            int MainCatalog = BairdLookUp.GetCatalogStartNode();
            if (this.CategoryId != 0)
            {
                IList<CatalogPathNode> path = CatalogDataSource.GetPath(CategoryId, false);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("NavTable");
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
                dt.Columns.Add("NavigateUrl", Type.GetType("System.String"));

                foreach (CatalogPathNode xPath in path)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(xPath.CatalogNodeId) != MainCatalog)
                    {
                        // Response.Write(xPath.Name + " ");
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Name"] = xPath.Name;
                        dr["NavigateUrl"] = xPath.NavigateUrl;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                BreadCrumbsRepeater.DataSource = ds;
                BreadCrumbsRepeater.DataMember = "NavTable";
                BreadCrumbsRepeater.DataBind();

            }
            else BreadCrumbsRepeater.Visible = false;

            //need to show/hide last node and show the current label

            if (_webpage != null)
            {
                if (BreadCrumbsRepeater.Controls.Count > 1)
                    CurrPageBCLbl.Text = " > ";
                if (_webpage.Title != "")
                    CurrPageBCLbl.Text += _webpage.Title;
                else
                    CurrPageBCLbl.Text += _webpage.Name;
            }
            else if (_product != null)
            {
                CurrPageBCLbl.Text = " > ";
                CurrPageBCLbl.Text += _product.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((HideLastNode) && (BreadCrumbsRepeater.Controls.Count > 0))
                {
                    BreadCrumbsRepeater.Controls[(BreadCrumbsRepeater.Controls.Count - 1)].Visible = false;
                    CurrPageBCLbl.Text += _category.Name;
                }
            }

            int count = 0;
            string label = CurrPageBCLbl.Text;
            foreach (RepeaterItem items in BreadCrumbsRepeater.Items)
            {
                HyperLink crumbs = items.FindControl("BreadCrumbsLink") as HyperLink;

                string str = crumbs.Text;

                foreach (char c in str)
                {
                    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c) || char.IsSeparator(c) || char.IsSymbol(c))
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (_product !=null)
                        {
                            string newString = crumbs.Text + label;
                            count++;

                        }
                    }
                }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the spaces within the product name by "`&nbsp;`"

```
dr["Name"] = xPath.Name.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

**OR**

with CSS:

```
dr["Name"] = "<span style=\"white-space:nowrap;\">" + xPath.Name + "</span>";
```

and you also need to modify this part:

```
<SeparatorTemplate> &gt; </SeparatorTemplate>
```

Comment: I am not sure why I would need to to this, though?

Comment: nbsp stands for "no-break space". This spaces won't be broken if the width is too small

Comment: If I use the nowrap property, though, the text will extend over the width of the page...

Comment: Yes, the same thing I've just noticed too. Please look at my updated post.